# Is it bad practice to modify a generated Swagger Client

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is it bad practice to modify a generated Swagger Client? I am trying to de-serialize a dictionary of long, strings which I know isn't technically supported. Is it bad practice to "hack" the generated Swagger client to support this?

Comment: It's only a bad-practice in that your code changes will be lost when the client is next generated.

Comment: Have you considered [creating a custom codegen template](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#making-your-own-codegen-modules) that would include your code changes? So that your custom code is always included in the generated client.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like from people I’ve talked to it’s not a huge deal to do this.